# I can't put a foreign key on a column

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I created these tables:

```
create table Angajati 
(
    ID_Angajat int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    Nume varchar(15) not null,
    Prenume varchar(30) not null,
    FunctieAngajat varchar(100) not null,
    NrTelefon int not null
);

create table PersonalLocatii
(
    ID_PersonalLocatii int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    CodLocatie int not null,
    foreign key (CodLocatie) references Locatii(CodLocatie),
    AdresaLocatie nvarchar(max) not null,
    FunctieAngajat varchar(100) not null,
    ID_Angajat int not null
);
go
```

I want to put a foreign key on column `ID_Angajat` in the `PersonalLocatii` table and I use this syntax:

```
alter table PersonalLocatii
    add constraint FK_ID_Angajat
        foreign key (ID_Angajat) references Angajati(ID_Angajat);
```

After modifying the column, it does not let me enter the information in the second table. the relationship between the first table and the second is one to many.

This is the error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ID_Angajat". The conflict occurred in database "Vegas", table "dbo.Angajati", column 'ID_Angajat'.

Please help me with that!

Comment: That means you already have values in your `ID_Angajat` column which do not match records in your `Angajati` table. You have to correct the data first.

Comment: Sounds like the table contains some data that does violates the constraint you are attempting to add, i.e. a value in the `ID_Angajat` is present in the second table but not the first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your data.

This query will help you find the "offending" rows.

```
Select ID_Angajat as Errant__ID_Angajat , * from 
PersonalLocatii child
where not exists (select ID_Angajat from Angajati innerParent where innerParent.ID_Angajat = child.ID_Angajat)
```

or a distinct list

```
Select Distinct Errant__ID_Angajat
from
(    Select ID_Angajat as Errant__ID_Angajat from 
    PersonalLocatii child
    where not exists (select ID_Angajat from Angajati innerParent where innerParent.ID_Angajat = child.ID_Angajat)
) derived1
```